# POST method in Django Rest framework returning server error 500 on EC2 instance

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, internal-server-error

I am trying to build a web app using Django Rest framework.

When I run the app on localhost 127.0.0.0/8000 it works fine. But when I deploy it on an EC2 server the POST methods return 500 server error.

Here is one of the post methods in the views.py -

```
class customer_location(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer_id = json.loads(request.body).get('customer_id')
        queryset = customers.objects.filter(cid= customer_id)
        serialize = customer_details(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The urls.py is like this -

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^customer_location/$', views.customer_location.as_view(), name='customer_location'),
]
```

The DEBUG mode is set to False and the EC2 instance IP address is added in the ALLOWED_HOSTS.

The GET methods are working fine but the POST methods give error.

As per SENTRY ERROR LOG the issue is -

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

And this is for this line in the view.py -

```
customer_id = json.loads(request.body).get('customer_id')
```

The inbound rules of the EC2 instance allows access for HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, PostgreSQL and Custom TCP rule for port 8000.

When I run the curl command from the terminal I can get the values for the POST Method-

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '{"customer_id":"1"}'   http://ec2_ip/customer_location/


output -

[{"cid":"1","name":"Rachel". "location":"NYC"}]
```

The curl command returns values for the POST method for the same EC2 server while the api end point on the EC2 server returns 500 server error.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try enabling DEBUG to see what the actual error is. `csrf` comes to mind.

Comment: The error log doesn't show anything. So I integrated sentry with the app. The sentry shows the error - raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Comment: @Seeker90 if you have error traceback, then add that in your question.

Comment: @NalinDobhal - Hi. I have added the error from sentry - It is raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Comment: Did you use 'django cors headers’?

Comment: @Shamim - Hey. I don't think so. Where can I check that ?

Comment: @Shamim we did not use django cors headers

Answer (score 1):

To resolve `cors` problem you should install `django-cors-headers` in your app.

1. At first install it by `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. Add `corsheaders` inside your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
     .....
]
```

3. Add `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` at the top of your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    .... 
]
```

4. Add the below line in anywhere inside the settings.py

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`

5. Finally add this line in settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

If your project runs properly with this configuration, then replace the '*' with your IP address. That's it!